# Back testing fixed income for bond portfolio management

Tags: fixed-income, data, callable-bonds

When doing back test trying to replicate a paper, how do you handle bonds that are maturing in an index?

Say I was trying to create a strategy, how do I account for bonds that mature in terms of return.

This question might be vague, thinking about it. But just wondering how authors considers bonds that mature and how the addition of bonds affect their study.